# Simple Modulo expression

Tags: java, operators

I understand that a mod operator finds the remainder of two numbers. However, I am having trouble understanding the concept when the numbers are reversed. Meaning, a smaller number comes first in the operation.

```
    int x = 4 % 3 ; // prints out 1
```

However, can someone explain this to me:

```
     int y = 1 % 4 ; //  prints out 1
     int z = 2 % 3 ; // prints out 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, i will fix that now

Answer (score 1):

Whether the left-hand side of the operator is larger than the right is irrelevant.  There is always a remainder for any division operation, it's just that sometimes it's 0.

So `5 % 2` returns `1`, just like `4 % 3` returns 1.

The value of any modulo operation of the form `x % n` will be 0 to `n - 1` inclusive, for positive `x`.  It will be `-1(n-1)` to 0 inclusive for negative `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the int y that prints out 2?

The int z though seems normal : 
2= 0*3 + **2**

int y = 1 % 4 should print 1 because:
1=0*4 + **1**

It works the same as when a bigger number comes first, you just take the remainder of the division of the first one by the second one.